# How can I implement a fast map having multiple keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers, stdmap

I'm looking for a C++ associative map container type which I can perform multiple key lookups on. The map needs to have constant time lookups, but I don't care if it's ordered or unordered. It just needs to be fast.

For example, I want to store a bunch of `std::vector` objects in a map with an `int` and a `void*` as the lookup keys. Both the `int` and the `void*` must match for my vector to be retrieved.

Does such a container exist already? Or am I going to have to roll my own? If so, how could I implement it? I've been trying to store a `boost::unordered_map` inside another `boost::unordered_map`, but I have not had any success with this method, yet. Maybe I will continue Pershing this method if there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant look up requires a hash map. You can use a the [boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/unordered.html) (or tr1). The key would be the [combined hash](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) of the int and the void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use boost, you can try `map< int, map<void*, vector> >`. The lookups are however O(log(map size)).

Answer (score 1):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can also use an [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), as it seems to fit your requirements quite nicely:

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity.

In order to combine your `int` and `void*` into a single key, you can make use of [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

To make the unordered map work with the pair, you have to specify a suitable hash function. In order to keep the following example short, I use a [handcrafted](https://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers) combination of `std::hash<>` function calls inside a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). In case this function causes performance problems, you might want to create a more sophisticated hash.

You didn't specify the content of your vectors, so I chose `int` for the sake of simplicity. However, you can adapt the solution to any vector content. All in all your code could look as follows:

```
using Key = std::pair<int, void*>;
auto hash = [](const Key & k) {
    return std::hash<int>()(k.first) * 31 + std::hash<void*>()(k.second);
};
std::unordered_map<Key, std::vector<int>, decltype(hash)> um(8, hash);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/IS60Dw)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

(although I think what you actually want is to use a type that contains both the void* and the integer as the key to your map, and just to compare the raw data for both in order to provide the comparison operator for the map)